# Python Pandas Regex: Search for strings with a wildcard in a column and return matches

Tags: python, regex, pandas, wildcard-expansion

I have a search list in a column which may contain a key: `'keyword1*keyword2'` to try to find the match in a separate dataframe column. How can I include the regex wildcard type `'keyword1.*keyword2'` `#using str.extract, extractall or findall?`

Using `.str.extract` works great matching exact substrings but I need it to also match substrings with wildcards in between the keyword.

```
# dataframe column or series list as keys to search for: 
dfKeys = pd.DataFrame()
dfKeys['SearchFor'] = ['this', 'Something', 'Second', 'Keyword1.*Keyword2', 'Stuff', 'One' ]

# col_next_to_SearchFor_col
dfKeys['AdjacentCol'] = ['this other string', 'SomeString Else', 'Second String Player', 'Keyword1 Keyword2', 'More String Stuff', 'One More String Example' ]

# dataframe column to search in: 
df1['Description'] = ['Something Here','Second Item 7', 'Something There', 'strng KEYWORD1 moreJARGON 06/0 010 KEYWORD2 andMORE b4END', 'Second Item 7', 'Even More Stuff']]

# I've tried:
df1['Matched'] = df1['Description'].str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(key['searchFor']), flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)
```

I've also tried substituting 'extract' from the code above with both 'extractall' and 'findall' but it still does not give me the results I need.
I expected `'Keyword1*Keyword2'` to match `"strng KEYWORD1 moreJARGON 06/0 010 KEYWORD2 andMORE b4END"`

UPDATE: The '.*' worked!
I'm also trying to add the value from the cell next to the matched key in 'SearchFor' column i.e. `dfKeys['AdjacentCol']`.

I've tried: 
    `df1['From_AdjacentCol'] = df1['Description'].str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(key['searchFor']), flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False).map(dfKeys.set_index('SearchFor')['AdjacentCol'].to_dict()).fillna('')` which works for everything but the keys with the wildcards.

```
# expected:
  Description                                      Matched            From_AdjacentCol
0 'Something Here'                                 'Something'         'this other string'
1 'Second Item 7'                                  'Second'            'Second String Player'
2 'Something There'                                'Something'         'this other string'  
3 'strng KEYWORD1 moreJARGON 06/0 010 KEYWORD2...' 'Keyword1*Keyword2' 'Keyword1 Keyword2'
4 'Second Item 7'                                  'Second'            'Second String Player'
5 'Even More Stuff'                                'Stuff'             'More String Stuff'
```

Any help with this is much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I haven't come across some similar questions but none of them address the wildcard aspect that I was having trouble with.

Comment: You are using `.str.extract` that does not use wildcards, it uses regex. Matching any chars between two strings is a too frequent regex issue, hence the duplicate reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

You are close to the solution, just change `*` to `.*`. Reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> .
>       (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any
>   character including a newline.
>
> *
>       Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’,
>   ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.

In Regular Expression star symbol `*` alone means nothing. It has a different meaning than the usual glob operator `*` in Unix/Windows file systems.

Star symbol is a quantifier (namely the *gready quantifier*), it must be associated to some pattern (here `.` to match any character) to mean something.

#### MCVE

Reshaping your MCVE:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

keys = ['this', 'Something', 'Second', 'Keyword1.*Keyword2', 'Stuff', 'One' ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Description'] = ['Something Here','Second Item 7', 'Something There',
                      'strng KEYWORD1 moreJARGON 06/0 010 KEYWORD2 andMORE b4END',
                      'Second Item 7', 'Even More Stuff']


regstr = '(%s)' % '|'.join(keys)

df1['Matched'] = df1['Description'].str.extract(regstr, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)
```

The regexp is now:

```
(this|Something|Second|Keyword1.*Keyword2|Stuff|One)
```

And matches the missing case:

```
                                         Description                                Matched
0                                     Something Here                              Something
1                                      Second Item 7                                 Second
2                                    Something There                              Something
3  strng KEYWORD1 moreJARGON 06/0 010 KEYWORD2 an...  KEYWORD1 moreJARGON 06/0 010 KEYWORD2
4                                      Second Item 7                                 Second
5                                    Even More Stuff                                  Stuff
```

Comment: Thanks! that's what it was. Any chance you know why `df1['col_Next_toMatched'] = df1['Description'].str.extract(regstr, flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False).map(dfKeys.set_index('keys')['col_Next_toKeys'].to_dict()).fillna('')` works for everything but the keys with wildcards?

Comment: @lodestar08 Could you update your post to show what is `dfKeys`?

Comment: I've updated the post - but not sure if that made it any clearer